# Find a relation in GAP

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, gap, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a finitely presented group $G$ and a finitely generated subgroup $H<G$. GAP computed that $H$ has finite index in $G$. However, PresentationSubgroupMtc(G,H) cannot compute the presentation ($[G:H]$ is a few thousands). I am wondering if its possible to find at least a few relations in $H$ using GAP.

Comment: You may get an answer here, but I recommend that you submit your question to the [GAP Forum](https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, the caveat that MTC usually provides far worse presentations that RRS. Are you sure you need MTC?

With this, if you look at the code for `PresentationSubgroupMtc` (in `your gapdirectory/lib/sgpres,gi`) you see that there is a rather brief function that computes an augmented coset table and then calls the function
`NEWTC_PresentationMTC` which rewrites the presentation relator-by-relator.  You could duplicate this code (renaming the functions) to have it return a partial set of relators.